# Passing Special Characters from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
                               CounterType  SumOfCount
0     Darrell L. Castle & Scott N. Bradley           0
1              Hillary Clinton & Tim Kaine         266
2                Jill Stein & Ajamu Baraka           1
3                 Gary Johnson & Bill Weld          14
4                        Registered Voters         519
5                        Times Blank Voted          12
6                            Times Counted         485
7                         Times Over Voted           0
8                                 Write-In           7
9       Donald J. Trump & Michael R. Pence         185
10  Gloria Estela La Riva & Eugene Puryear           0
11           Alyson Kennedy & Osborne Hart           0
```

I'm new to working with Python and Pandas. How could I escape the special characters from the CounterType column?